# Doing grep and sed in a single command line

Tags: arrays, linux, perl

I have written a perl script with two arrays. My first array contains a list of names and my second array contains a list of names that I would like to replace the first names with.

This is a quick and dirty script I'm writing just to get something done so I do not have to do the manual work. It's not something I am focusing on looking "clean" or super efficient. For that reason, I'm making use of `system` a lot.

A sample directory that I am using would look like this:

> /myDir/Names/John/ containing files John.log, John.txt, RandomFile.html

John.log

```
John is an engineer.
Jack and John are friends.
```

John.txt

```
John is 48 years old.
```

where John is an element in my first array. I want to be able to replace John with, for example, Mary from my second array IN FILES THAT CONTAIN JOHN IN THE FILE NAME. I want the element of that array to change to the corresponding element number in the next array. Here is what I've come up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @firstnames = (John, Jack, Jill);
my @secondnames = (Mary, Nick, Joseph);

foreach my $old (@firstnames){
    foreach my $new (@secondnames){
         system("grep -rl $old /myDir/Names/$old/ | xargs sed -i 's/$old/$new/g' $old.* ");
        system("rename '$old' '$new' /myDir/Names/$old.*");
     }
}
```

Grep seems to work fine, Rename and Sed does not because of the '.*'. The issue is where I have `$old.*`. It appropriately substitutes $old with the correct element in the array but it looks for files called `John.*`, `Jack.*`, `Jill.*` instead of reading `.*` as any file extension. Clearly, I am not understanding how sed works entirely. I would like some help as to how I can do the sed command for all files containing `$old` wit ANY file extension, because there might be multiple files in the directories with same names and different extensions. The reason I specify the first name with any extension is because the file might contain something like `RandomFile.html` that I listed above and I only want files that contain `$old` before extension.

This is the output that I want, where the files names along with the words found in the text will be replaced with the corresponding element from the second array:

Mary.log

```
Mary is an engineer.
Jack and Mary are friends.
```

Mary.txt

```
Mary is 48 years old.
```

Note: The words that are in the file, match the name of the file they are in, which match the name of the directory they are in. That is the pattern of these Directories and their files.

Please let me know if anything is unclear and I will edit my post.

Comment: Do it all in Perl. There should be far fewer issues and tricks to deal with.

Comment: @zdim I'm not sure how to do it all in perl so I was just looking for quick linux commands to put together to have things done on the spot since I want to get this figured out by today.

Comment: To get lists of files/directories in a directory you can use `glob` or `opendir`+`readdir` ... but you seem to know what filenames to expect -- are those `@names` really to be hardcoded?

Comment: @zdim In my script, I am extracting two columns from a csv file and the first column is pushed into an array and the second column is pushed into another array. However, that part works fine and didn't seem relevant to my question so I did not include. In the end, I have arrays that are populated like I wrote above, with names from those columns in the excel sheet.

Comment: (1) Since you have names then you don't need `glob` and such -- just compose filenames to open and edit.  Rename files with `move` from `File::Copy`, for instance  (2) "_opportunity to get real familiar with linux commands_"  -- fair enough :).  I don't know that it's the best way though but it's a worthy purpose :)

Comment: @zdim Thanks for the tip! The reason I just used rename is that way I wouldn't have to add in that extra line to remove the original files after the `move`. (lazy much) However, my main issue is getting it to replace the instance of the previous name inside the file itself :/ Not the rename of the file.

Comment: Right, I got that; the question is clear.  (I was just telling you how to do the job in Perl.)  I don't see what's wrong with `sed`-part of pipeline ... it doesn't get correct filenames from `xargs`?

Comment: @zdim It says there is no input file now for sed. Also it seems I will have to take your advice on doing `mv` in Perl because using `system` I cannot do `rename` with `.*` file extensions.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue here is that you're piping a list of filenames into xargs already which get passed to sed. You cannot have sed take the intersection of all filenames that have the desired words in them AND the contents of those files as well. You will need to first find all the files with the desired contents, filter out the filenames you do not care about, THEN feed that list into xargs sed. Try:

```
system("grep -rl $old /myDir/Names/$old/ | grep $old | xargs sed -i 's/$old/$new/g'");
```

Comment: From what I understand, first grep is getting all file names that have `$old`, the second grep is getting contents with $old, then the sed is changing $old in content to $new?

Comment: No - other way around. First grep gets all files that have $old in them, the second grep filters to only those FILENAMES that have $old in them, and the xargs sed should be changing all instances of $old in the files to $new.

Comment: It says sed: no input files, when I do this.

Comment: Note: I've come to find that this is due to an issue with grep itself. I'll have to debug what's going on with grep that is failing to find the files.

Comment: It worked for me fine. It's possible perl isn't expanding your command right. Try to execute set -x before running your command, like "set -x && grep -rl..."

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues with grep that I was not able to entirely trace down so I used `find` instead which seems to do the trick. Here is what I'm using now that works just fine:

`find ./$old -name "$old.*" -exec gsed -i -e "s/$old/$new/Ig" {} +`

Another important issue to note that is not particularly related to the problem in the question is that I am incorrectly using the `foreach` loop. In order to match each element in the arrays, you have to iterate through the size of the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = scalar @firstnames;
for ($i=0; $i < @firstnames; $i++){
.......
 }
```

Comment: Comment on your Perl loop (I use `for` instead of the more common `foreach` for brevity here; they are synonyms).  (1) To iterate over array _elements_ you want `for my $elem (@ary)` (2) If you need to iterate over the _index_, a nice way is `for my $i (0..$#ary)`, where `$#ary` is syntax for the index of the last element.  (3) With a C-style `for` loop (needed _very_ rarely) it'd be `for (my $i = 0; $i < @ary; ++$i)`, where we don't need the array size first since in `$i < @ary` the array is in the scalar context and then its size is used.

Answer (score 0):

.Hi sfr.  This will do the job although there is no error checking.

```
#!perl

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use File::Glob "bsd_glob";
use List::MoreUtils "mesh";
use Data::Dumper "Dumper";
our $basedir = "/myDir/Names";
our @oldnames = qw/John Jack Jill/;
our @newnames = qw/Mary Nick Joseph/;
our %namemap = mesh @oldnames, @newnames;
printf "oldnames:%s\nnewnames: %s\nnamemap:%s\n\n", map Dumper($_), \@oldnames, \@newnames, \%namemap;

foreach my $searchname (keys %namemap) {
    print "searchname: $searchname, glob: $basedir/$searchname/*$searchname*";
    my @files = bsd_glob "$basedir/$searchname/*$searchname*";
    printf "files %s\n", Dumper \@files;

    next unless @files;
    local $/;
    foreach my $file (@files) {
        print "on file $file\n";
        open my $F, "+<", $file or die "open $file: $!";
        my $text = readline $F;
        print "changing all $searchname to $namemap{$searchname}\n";
        if (my $c = $text =~ s/\b$searchname\b/$namemap{$searchname}/g) {
            print "replaced $c occurrences\n";
            seek $F, 0, 0 or die "seek $file: $!";
            print $F $text or die "print $file: $!";
            print "wrote changes to file\n";
            close $F or die "closing $file: $!";
        }
        else { print "file did not contain any $searchname\n"; }
        (my $newfile = $file) =~ s/\b$searchname\b/$namemap{$searchname}/g;
        print "renaming $file to $newfile\n";
        rename $file, $newfile or die "rename: $!";
    }
}
```

LA

EDIT: code updated

Comment: So I used data dumper to print the hash %namemap which gives the desired output. However ,when I do a print on $searchname it only prints about 4 of the keys and then the program dies saying no such file or directory at the last line. But when I do `print "$_\n" for keys %namemap;` it prints everything out just fine....

Comment: ***3 of the keys

Comment: $searchname doesn't seem to be each key like it should be. I've tried varying the array size and each time, it only takes some of the hash keys for the foreach loop and not the rest so the program dies at `rename` because that key doesn't exist (even thought the hash looks perfectly fine when displaying content with data dumper)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to say.  If a $searchname doesn't exist then the rename cannot even be reached.  I'll update the code with some diagnostics.  If it doesn't work, post the output showing the error message.